# Steps to connect SQLitedatabse with QT.?

Tags: database, qt, sqlite, connection

I am very new on QT and I have been trying to connect my SQLite database file in QT to read the data for my program. But after spending good time on Google I have only found three lines

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("D:\\Rahul DB files\\MobileDB.s3db");
    bool db_ok = db.open();
```

but I am unable to connect to the DB. I'll be highly obliged if the few initial steps that will be required to connect will be annotated. Thank You

Comment: Btw... please Qt and not QT. Qt is a cross-platform application development framework, but QT (QuickTime) - is an extensible multimedia framework developed by Apple Inc.

Comment: I am new will take care of it in future. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","D:\\Rahul DB files\\MobileDB.s3db");
db.open()
```

Ok, a little more explanation. With your addDatabase("QSQLITE") you open a default sqlite database connection. Which one? Sqlite has no server. Any arbitrary file could be a sqlite database. With setDatabaseName you just rename the connection. From the QSqlDatabase docs:

> **Note:** The database name is not the connection name. The connection
>   name must be passed to addDatabase() at connection object create time.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you did compile sqlite support static or provide (relative to you executable) `sqldrivers/qsqlite.dll`. You eventually need to compile necessary sql-drivers. Check out the documentation at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/sql-driver.html

Comment: Your qsqlite driver needs to reside in the ``sqldrivers`` directory. Eventually you can examine which drivers are loaded? Try ``QSqlDatabase::drivers()`` for a list of currently available drivers by your app